# Why is my self-created package not in site-packages?

Tags: python, package

I am learning to create a package in python. This is the structure of the packages

```
funniest
   -- funniest
      -- __init__.py
   -- setup.py
```

**init**.py

```
def joke():
    return (u'Wenn ist das Nunst\u00fcck git und Slotermeyer? Ja! ... '
        u'Beiherhund das Oder die Flipperwaldt gersput.')
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='funniest',
      version='0.1',
      description='The funniest joke in the world',
      url='http://github.com/storborg/funniest',
      author='Flying Circus',
      author_email='flyingcircus@example.com',
      license='EXXX',
      packages=['funniest'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Then I did in venv

```
source bin/activate
python setup.py develop
python setup.py install
```

Then I wanted to use the package in my local python script in the venv

```
from funniest import * // I get error here. ImportError: No module named funniest
```

but the package cannot be imported in the script. So I went and checked the site-packages, I saw **funniest.egg-link** and all the imports fail. Can anyone explain why it is not in the site-package or how to actually make the 'funniest' package usable locally?

Update : I also tried the following but my package is not listed in the output

```
yolk -l
```

Comment: make sure you're using the same python enviroment and can you share more details about " all the imports fail"?

Comment: @Guoliang I am using the same environment. I've updated the error message that I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

I created a project using the same sturcuture as your project:

```
python setup.py develop
...Processing dependencies for funniest==0.1
...Finished processing dependencies for funniest==0.1
```

I double checked the `funniest.egg-link` in site-packages, it points to `projects/funniest`, looks good. 
then I did a `pip list`, funniest is in the list

```
funniest (0.1)
```

then I start `python` using the same python environment, it works exactly as expected:

```
(venv) \projects\funniest>python
>>> from funniest import joke
>>> joke.joke()
hi
```

I created joke.py with a joke() funciton under projects/funniest/funniest.

please double check you're using the same python enviroment. hope it helps.